# How to Open React Native's Screen from Native Android Activity?

Tags: android, react-native

There is Button in android Activity.
When I click on button in Android then it should be open React Native screen.
I want to redirect from Android To React Native.
How to Open React Native's Screen from Native Android Activity?

I want to redirect from Android To React Native.

Comment: Have you tried launching the React Native app's activity?

Comment: plz guide step by step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to launch an Activity from another Application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/how-to-launch-an-activity-from-another-application-in-android)